# Cookie domain issue. Have to clear cache to log back in. HELP.

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm new in Magento and this cookie session management really kick my arse off. I have no problem login on fresh browser **BUT** after I close my browser or logout, I can't log back in unless I clear the cache and it's getting too much. Here is my Session cookie management

[image]

and here is the screenshot of browser cookies

[image]

Comment: Try setting Use HTTP Only and all the Session Validation Settings to No